# ssh between Nitrous.io boxes?

Tags: ssh, nitrousio

Has anyone else had luck trying to ssh between two Nitrous.io boxes?  For example:
Box 1: Hosting mongo & rails server
Box 2: AngularJS app that talks to rails API

I'd like to be able to ssh from Box 2 to Box 1r so I can tail the logs over there.

You may ask, why would I do such a thing?  Basically my main dev laptop is having memory issues so I've been using a chromebook.  Its actually not bad at all except for the lack of a proper terminal.

I've added the public key from Box 2 to Box 1.  But it won't let me connect.  Has anyone had any luck with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you can SSH into a Nitrous box, but establishing an SSH connection from a Nitrous box to another is not supported. You may want to look into using WebSockets instead.

Comment: Good idea, I'll give that a go.  Have you set that up yourself?

Comment: I haven't myself, but I would just recommend looking into WebSockets documentation for the frameworks you are working with. If you do run into any specific issues there then I'd be glad to help out.